# How to plot 2 time series lines and their trend lines in r

Tags: r, time-series, trendline

I have the code given below. I have data in 3 columns in csv file having columns names as Year, GAC and A1C.
I use the code, it just plots time series of only GAC  and it also plots its trend line as well as shown in figure  [image]

How I can plot both the time series lines of GAC and A1C and their trend lines on the same graph in the code. Please help

```r
h=ggplot(Data, aes(Year, GAC, group=1, xaxt='n', las=2))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,size= 1.5)
```

Comment: You're blending base and `ggplot2` options: `xaxt='n', las=2` don't belong in ggplot. Also, `group=1` should likely be outside `aes(...)`, as it is static and does not depend on anything in the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

`ggplot2` really wants data in a "long" format, so I suggest you reshape your data from "wide" (3 columns) to "long" (2 columns). There are multiple ways to do this, SO has many questions about "reshape wide to long", but here is one.

Lacking your data, here is something random.

```r
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame(Year = 1900 + 1:50, GAC = cumsum(runif(50)), Unk = cumsum(rnorm(50)))
head(dat)
#   Year      GAC        Unk
# 1 1901 0.914806 -0.4304691
# 2 1902 1.851881 -0.6877385
# 3 1903 2.138021 -2.4509016
# 4 1904 2.968469 -1.9908042
# 5 1905 3.610214 -2.6307991
# 6 1906 4.129310 -2.1753490

# library(tidyr)
head(tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, GAC:Unk))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
#    Year name   value
#   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
# 1  1901 GAC    0.915
# 2  1901 Unk   -0.430
# 3  1902 GAC    1.85 
# 4  1902 Unk   -0.688
# 5  1903 GAC    2.14 
# 6  1903 Unk   -2.45
```

And a plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(tidyr::pivot_longer(dat, GAC:Unk), aes(Year, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE, size = 1.5)
```

[image: sample ggplot2]

There are ways, of course, to do this without reshaping the data. I discourage this for two reasons:

1. it does not scale well, requiring you to add a new `geom_line` for each line series you want to plot (as well as `geom_smooth` if you want it); and
2. if you want a legend, then it tends to be much easier to allow `ggplot` to handle that for you. This can only be done (well/easily) when `ggplot` handles the groups/lines.

```r
ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Year)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = GAC), color = "red", data = dat) +
  geom_smooth(aes(Year, GAC), data = dat, color = "red", method = lm, se = FALSE, size = 1.5) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Unk), color = "blue", data = dat) +
  geom_smooth(aes(Year, Unk), data = dat, color = "blue", method = lm, se = FALSE, size = 1.5)
```